# Is there any way to use one static folder for all apps in django project

Tags: python, django

I would like to ask if it is possible to use one static folder for all your project apps in `django`? I'm building my app on `windows 10`.

Supposed that we have this structure:

```
src
...\projectFolder
......\__init__.py
......\settings.py
......\urls.py
......\wsgi.py
...\app1
......\app1
.........\static
...\app2
......\app2
.........\static
...\app3
......\app3
.........\static
...manage.py
```

To avoid multiple static folder each app i would like to make this structure so static folder is shared in all the applications with the same level directory of `projectFolder`.

```
src
...\static          // this is static folder that must be shared with all the apps.
...\projectFolder
......\__init__.py
......\settings.py
......\urls.py
......\wsgi.py
...\app1
...\app2
...\app3
...manage.py
```

**Is this possible?**

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Once you've run collectstatic, the individual static folders are all collected into one place. There is nothing stopping any app accessing files from anywhere.

Comment: so that means that you can access some app static folder to another app?

Comment: I'm not even sure what you mean by "access". Static files are things like images and js loaded separately by the browser. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i would like to use one static folder for all the apps of a project sir sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/) (albeit possibly not in the most beginner-friendly way). What you want is to add your project's level "static" directory to `settings.STATICFILES_DIRS`.